# how to include jwplayer in drupal site

Tags: drupal-6, jwplayer

I have installed a JW Player in my drupal site and included the video link into it to display the video in jw player. But the video is not played into it. Please if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some more information could help.

To be on the safe side, follow the configuration wizard here:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard

Copy the code and put it on the corresponding drupal part that you you want it to appear.

If the problem persists, put the error message so we can be more specific.